# How to assign custom template to specific products in Woocommerce?

Tags: themes, plugins

I figured out how to assign a template to a product category (from this thread [Different template of products for specific category. WooCommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61667/different-template-of-products-for-specific-category-woocommerce)), but I'm wondering if I can assign a custom template to specific products.

EDIT: For more clarity, I want to have a certain style applied to the category page, but when I click on one of those products, I want to keep that same style.

Comment: so basically you want all products of a certain category to have a differente style?

Comment: @dbeja That is correct, I want products of category X to have a custom single-product.php template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the changes you need are strictly CSS, you can add the category names as classes to the [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) via the `body_class` filter.

```
add_filter('body_class','wpa76627_class_names');
function wpa76627_class_names( $classes ) {
    if( is_singular( 'product' ) ):
        global $post;
        foreach( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) as $cat )
            // maybe you want to make this more unique, like:
            // $classes[] = 'product-category-' . $cat->slug;
            $classes[] = $cat->slug;
    endif;
    return $classes;
}
```

This code checks if we are viewing a single product page, then loops over all product_cats, adding the slugs as classes to the body tag. This could also be adapted for any post type or taxonomy.

Comment: Would I add this to my theme functions file?

Comment: And I'm not quite there yet. Do I change `wpa76627_class_names` or `slug` to the category name?

Comment: yes, you can just copy/paste that into your functions.php file. you don't have to change anything if you don't want to. in your style.css file, you can target items via a selector like `body.some-category-slug h1.product-title` to style it per-category

Comment: I see what you mean now. I added it to the functions file but when I view source the body tag does not have any classes attached to it.

Comment: your theme has to have the `body_class` function: `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`

Comment: Ah, awesome. Thanks! I'll vote you up when I get enough rep. points.