# Is it possible Different templates of products for specific category in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, customization

For example i have category **Hostels & Bikes**, and one template for Hostels single product template, but for category Bikes i want to have different single-product.php template, how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a taxonomy-product_cat-bikes.php template inside a woocommerce folder in your theme.  For more info here is the [github link](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/taxonomy-product_cat.php) of the template file.

Here are some resources for you:

[More solutions to fit your needs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61667/different-template-of-products-for-specific-category-woocommerce)

[WooCommerce template docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: Thank You. but how to call this file in woocommerce?

Comment: Woocommerce uses it if the current category being viewed matches with the slug (bikes).  Make sure to create a woocommerce folder inside of your main theme directory and add the template file inside of it (taxonomy-product_cat-bikes.php).  Add a line like echo 'test'; to that file and go to the category page depending on how you set it up in the permalinks, you should see the word "test".